# Error in Kubernetes cronjob to dump and restore postgres database for Django application

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I need to create a testing environment for a specific team to use our Django application for testing against the database. This database must be somewhat in sync with out production database. Considering we have two clusters `production` and `staging`, my approach is the following:

- Create a `db_test` in the staging Postgres server
- `db_test` will be periodically synced with `db_prod`. To do so:
- Create a cronjob in the `staging` cluster that connects to the production database, do a `pg_dump` and then do a `pg_restore` to the `db_test` (using `localhost` because it's connected through a pgbouncer).
- I run the migrations to make sure the tables are up to date
- Next: I need to run a management command that will erase some customer data from this copy (to be GDPR compliant).

Desired behavior:

- `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` are successful and the new database is cleared of customer information

Actual behaviour:

- `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` are successful. I can `psql` into the newly created database and everything looks alright.
- `migrate` command fails with the traceback below
- `clean_db` fails because it can't find some tables (which they exist as I inspected with `psql`.

This is the simple shell script I run in the cronjob:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# Dump the database locally
pg_dump --host=mydb.postgres.database.azure.com \
        --username=myuser@production \
        --no-owner \
        --verbose \
        -Ft db_prod > $HOME/db_prod-$(date +%F).tar &&

sleep 30 &&

# Restore the database
pg_restore --no-owner \
    --no-acl \
    --host='localhost' \
    --user=myuser@staging \
    --port=5432 \
    --clean \
    --dbname=db_test \
    $HOME/db_prod-$(date +%F).tar \
    --verbose &&

python manage.py migrate &&

python manage.py clean_db
```

- This is the error of the `clean_db` without the `migrate` before

```sh
relation "uploader_somemodel" does not exist
2
LINE 1: SELECT COUNT(*) AS "__count" FROM "uploader_somemodel...
```

But this is the log of the table being created

````sh
pg_restore: processing data for table "public.uploader_somemodel"```
````

- And this is the error log of the `migrate` command

```sh
Running all migrations...
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, auth, axes, contenttypes, django_mfa, myapp, reversion, sessions, uploader, userapi
Running migrations:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/migrations/recorder.py", line 67, in ensure_schema
    editor.create_model(self.Migration)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 307, in create_model
    self.execute(sql, params or None)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/opt/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 82, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMA...
                     ^
```

Has anyone ever encountered a similar error and know what this is about? Or even better, do you have a suggestion of how I could perform this diferently?

Answer (score 0):

Did you change the NAME of the db in your env variable ?
To get this result in your django settings.py:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': db_test,
        'USER': POSTGRES_USER,
        'PASSWORD': POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
        'HOST': POSTGRES_HOST,
        'PORT': 5432,
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. The env variables are set in the cronjob. I can enter the container and execute a Django shell, for example but the other commands fail miserably